# How do I get values from a textbox that was created in a UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I've got a UserControl that has two textboxes in it. Users can add Multiple copies of these UserControls as needed. Each UserControl is added to the bottom of a Panel. How would I go about getting information from these UserControls.

This is the code to add the UserControl that I'm currently Using:

```
        private void btnAddMailing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Set the Panel back to 0,0 Before adding a control to avoid Huge WhiteSpace Gap
            pnlMailingPanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0,0);

            /*I know this isn't the best way of keeping track of how many UserControls 
            I've added to the Panel, But it's what i'm working with right now.*/
            int noOfMailings=0;
            foreach (Control c in pnlMailingPanel.Controls)
            {
                if (c is MailingReference)
                    noOfMailings++;
            }
            //Add the New MailingReference to the bottom of the Panel
            /*1 is the type of Mailing, noOfMailings Determines how many mailings we've sent for 
            this  project*/
            MailingReference mr = new MailingReference(1, noOfMailings);
            mr.Location = new Point(MRXpos, MRYpos);
            MRYpos += 120;
            pnlMailingPanel.Controls.Add(mr);
        }
```

And here's the code for the MailingReference Class:

```
public partial class MailingReference : UserControl
{
    public String Date
    {
        get { return txtDate.Text; }
        set { txtDate.Text = value; }
    }
    public String NumberSent
    {
        get { return txtNoSent.Text; }
        set { txtNoSent.Text = value; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a Panel for a Mailing
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_letterType">Type of 0 Letter, 1 Initial, 2 Final, 3 Legal, 4 Court</param>
    public MailingReference(int _letterType, int _mailingNo)
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        //alternate colors
        if (_mailingNo % 2 == 0)
            panel1.BackColor = Color.White;
        else
            panel1.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        switch (_letterType)
        {
            case 1:
                lblLetter.Text = "Initial";
                break;
            case 2:
                lblLetter.Text = "Final";
                break;
            case 3:
                lblLetter.Text = "Legal";
                break;
            case 4:
                lblLetter.Text = "Court";
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
        lblMailingNumber.Text = _mailingNo.ToString();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Parent.Controls.Remove(this);
    }
```

I've tried using

```
 foreach (Control c in pnlMailingPanel.Controls)
        {
            if (c is MailingReference)
            {
                foreach (Control c2 in MailingReference.Controls)
                {
                    //do work
                }
            }
        }
```

to get the data from the textboxes, but MailingReference.Controls doesn't exist.

I'm not sure how to go about looping through each MailingReference UserControl and getting the Data from the two textboxes in each one. Any Tips?

Comment: Ugh. I don't suppose you can switch to WPF/MVVM

Comment: One thing that just popped into my head would be using a List<MailingReference> mrList = new List<MailingReference>() to keep track of all of the Controls that were added. Would this be the best way to loop through everyone of them?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET It's a Windows From Application, I've never worked with WPF to be honest with you.

Comment: I can see that its WinForms, its just this whole process is *really* painful in WinForms, and really easy in WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As near as I can tell, the main thing you have wrong is that you are trying to access the instance property `Controls` via the class name. You should have this instead:

```
foreach (Control c in pnlMailingPanel.Controls)
{
    MailingReference mailingReference = c as MailingReference;

    if (mailingReference != null)
    {
        foreach (Control c2 in mailingReference.Controls)
        {
            //do work
        }
    }
}
```